# UIView Modal Popup with Embedded UITableView with UIToolbar, Toolbar moves with Table

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

This is driving me insane!   (ios 5+, ARC)

Pretty simple concept here: 
I have a `UIView` with an embedded `UITableView`, when clicking on a specific cell, I have iOS launch a `modalview` with a segue. 
This `modalview`, is a `UIView` with an Embedded `UITableView` in it, filled with names from a data source.  You can choose multiple items in this view (using `cellaccessory: checkmark)`

**The Goal**
Get some sort of "Done" button to show up

Ok, so after much running around, I am to understand that Modal windows do not, in fact, allow `navigationController` items. No `toolbars`, no `Navigationbars` by default.
Ok, so I'll create my own.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSInteger tbHeight = 50;
    UIToolbar *tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - tbHeight), self.view.frame.size.width, tbHeight)];
    tb.translucent = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneAction:)];

    NSArray *barButton  =   [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flexibleSpace,doneButton,nil];
    [tb setItems:barButton];


    [self.view addSubview:tb];

    barButton = nil;

    //....

}
```

Simple enough right?

Well, the `toolbar` does show up, for sure. BUT, it doesnt stick to the bottom like its supposed to. In fact, when you scroll the embedded `tableview` up and down, the `UIToolbar` goes with it, almost like its stuck on the `tablevie` somehow.

Ive been looking for hours for solutions, I've come across nothing. Wondering if anybody here has any ideas?

If you need more information, please by all means, enquire :)

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious, but what viewController is this a `viewDidLoad` method for, and are you sure that `self.view` is not the tableView?

Comment: `This modal view, is a UIView with an Embedded UITableView in it,` :)  From the **.h**: `@interface MultipleChoiceViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {`

Comment: I'm not sure why you think modal views can't have a tool bar -- I've added one to the view of a UIViewController sub lass with an embedded table view, and everything works as it should.

Comment: Its something I read from various sources, besides when I set the toolbar and navigation bar hidden values to NO, they still dont show up, yet the moment I switch the segue from Modal to Push, they show up. Googling around told me that Modals dont have navigation controllers, it can be forced but the default available ones not so much.    The problem I suffer at this very point in time, is that my toolbar moves with my UITableView, despite _not_ making the Toolbar a child view of the UITableView :\

Comment: No, modals don't have navigation controllers, but we're talking about a tool bar here not a navigation bar. The way I did it was to drag a toolbar to the bottom of a UIViewController's view, then drag in a table view, and size it so it ends somewhat above the toolbar. I used a modal segue, which worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that your toolbar is scrolling with the table if it's a `UIViewController` subclass, unless you've assigned a UITableView to self.view or something... But since it is, this is what I do when adding a fixed item to a table view:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    tb.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-tb.bounds.size.height+scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, tb.bounds.size.height);

}
```

Comment: Ah thats badass, I totally didnt even notice this override :)   Cheers!